# AdoptOpenJDK Class Documentation

Tags: java, adoptopenjdk

Is there a website like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html to see the documentation of a class or its (available) methods for **AdopOpenJDK**?

Answer (score 3):

We can use the [Javadoc published by Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html).

Reasoning:

AdoptOpenJDK does not provide an own JDK/JVM. [As stated on their website](https://adoptopenjdk.net/):

> AdoptOpenJDK uses infrastructure, build and test scripts to produce prebuilt binaries from OpenJDK™ class libraries and a choice of either the OpenJDK HotSpot or Eclipse OpenJ9 VM.

So in essence, they build the OpenJDK. As long as a release has not yet reached its End-Of-Life, OpenJDK builds are provided by Oracle. After that, the OpenJDK is responsible for developing the OpenJDK project. Since, however, both JDKs pass the [JCK-tests](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/), they are drop-in replacements for each other. Thus, you can use the official Oracle Javadoc.

There is, as far as I know, no dedicated Javadoc-homepage for OpenJDK, although [there is a corresponding issue in the AdoptOpenJDK github](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/695).

Comment: This Answer is correct, referring to *Java SE* (Standard Edition). For the API documentation for the classes formerly known as *Java EE (Enterprise Edition)*, now known as *Jakarta EE*, see the [Jakarta.ee Specifications](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/) page.

Comment: It is maybe worth noting (explicitly) that there is no need for a separate AdoptOpenJDK doc site, because the javadocs would be identical to those on the Oracle site.  The same applies to the OpenJDK site.  (Different groups running different sites hosting identical content is largely pointless.  If the Oracle site was unreliable or slow, there might be a point.  But it isn't.)

Comment: @Stephen C, the claim that the javadocs would be identical is not correct.  Look at the Thread.isAlive() method's javadoc in the [Oracle Java 11 JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive()) and the corresponding java file in the src.zip included with the AdoptOpenJDK OpenJ9 install.  The comments for these two public methods are not the same.  They both effectively "say the same thing", however, they are not, strictly speaking, identical.  If there are enough other differences, then asking for a separate generation may well be justified

Comment: @Scrubbie OpenJ9 is not the "default" VM, it is the Eclipse-Implementation. The "default" is the OpenJDK HotSpot VM.

Comment: *"If there are enough other differences, then asking for a separate generation may well be justified"* - This is hypothetical.  Note that there are always likely to be small differences between the official javadocs for Java X and what the src.zip files say for the release of Java X that you have downloaded.  This applies for the official Oracle and OpenJDK downloadables too.  Why?  Because they represent snapshots of the codebase taken at different points in time.  Does it matter?  In practice No.  But what if it did?  Well then it is a problem for the Oracle javadocs too!!

Comment: Now if the Java SE libraries in (say) OpenJ9 actually *diverged* from the std OpenJDK code line, or there was a significant lag in changes in OpenJDK reaching OpenJ9, then there would be a (IMO weak) case for a separate public javadoc site for OpenJ9.  But I doubt that such a (hypothetical) OpenJ9 javadoc site would get much traffic.  Not enough to justify the cost of setting up and running it.

Comment: I just looked at the issue link that Turing85 found.  (See answer ^^^).  No sign of any action on the issue in ~2.5 years.  The comments don't indicate that there is huge demand for this "enhancement" ...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to answer this question is to use debian / ubuntu packages `openjdk-11-doc`

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-doc
```

Then html static file will be available in this directory : `/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc`